# why my Ubuntu 10.10 CD player can not read CD files copies from WinXP

Tags: 10.10, software-recommendation, multimedia

Before installing Ubuntu 10.10 I made four Verbatim DVD CD copies of all my files in WindowsXP.Laptop Fujitsu Simens Amilo.

After installation of Ubuntu 10.10 the CD player managed to read and show only one DVD with
music folder.Other three with mixed pictures and documents it does not recognize and show nothing.OPEN WITH gave no results.

What tools must I have in my new Ubuntu 10.10 to enable CD player to see and read my files from ex WindowsXP?

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem in the past. It turned out that the CDs were not properly closed by Windows, Those were sessions.

But if you can, transfer the files from the CD to a USB device and read it from Linux. I know that this may not be the solution you want, but it could do the trick for you. Alternatively, you may try to actually close the CD under Windows. There should be ab option under a menu for this, once you explore the actual CD content itself. Also, you may want to try something like Nero to close the actual CD.

Answer (score 0):

There is a specific DVD file

http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/10.10/release/

If you try burning the CD file to a DVD, it won't work (at least on a macbook).